# Increase the Number of item if its out of stock

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just gonna ask what's the best way to do Increase the number of items if it's out of stock or below 100.

Like Medicine is 95 and you input 5 then click add button then the result will be 100.

```
<td>{{ $medicine->medicine_qty }}
    <input style="width: 50px;" class="box" type="number" id="qty"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="addMed">Add</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="minusMed">Minus</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Use if statement, if qty < 100 then add.

Comment: how should i get the value of the inputed number by the user through the ID=qty? like if ({{ $medicine->medicine_qty }} <100) {{ $medicine->medicine_qty }} + qty?

Answer (score 0):

In front end you can add **name** tag in your buttons and in backend have a code something like this:

```
<td>{{ $medicine->medicine_qty }}
    <input style="width: 50px;" class="box" type="number" id="qty" name="qty"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="addMed" name="addMed">Add</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="minusMed" name="minusMed">Minus</button>
</td>
```

```
$qty = $request->get('qty');
if($request->get('addMed')){
   // add value to your medicine 
   $yourModelValue += $qty;
} elseif($request->get(''){
   // remove value from medicine
   $yourModelValue -= $qty;
}
```

Comment: so should i put that in the controller like
 public function medValue(Request $request)
    {
        $qty = $request->get('qty');
if($request->get('addMed')){
   // add value to your medicine 
   $yourModelValue += $qty;
} elseif($request->get(''){
   // remove value from medicine
   $yourModelValue -= $qty;
}
    }

Answer (score 0):

You will need to submit a request if you want to update the data. If you want a button press to trigger it without leaving or refreshing the page, then you'll probably want to make an AJAX request and have it update the value in the database, then return the new value you will want to reflect on the page.